# svg-import.js import error "SVG Import got unexpected type sodipodi:namedview "

Tags: javascript, plugins, svg, svg.js

I am using svgjs for loading SVG and to do some manipulations.
I also use svg-import plugin for importing already existing svg file.
but I am getting the error:

```
SVG Import got unexpected type sodipodi:namedview
```

while trying to load an SVG. It does have the sodipodi:namedview tag and proper namespaces are also included. It is correctly loading in browsers editors and even the svg-edit project.

Can anybody tell me how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I realize this is an ancient question, but the answer to this is most likely that you are importing an Inkscape svg that hasn't been exported as plain svg. Inkscape puts in an extra tag set named sodipodi.

You can either strip that out manually or use "save as" in Inkscape to save a plain svn copy. If you click "Save As..." you will see a drop down list in the lower right corner of the dialog box where you can select "Plain SVG."